# SQL query with multiple date ranges and Full Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a SQL query running a FULL JOIN on multiple database tables. The query is dynamic based on user input but for the example I just included some possible inputs.

This issue I'm having is I need to filter by multiple date ranges and return the query results if they fall within either date range.

The query as I have now is:

```
SELECT rank=COUNT(*)
   FROM    [LOM].[dbo].[lom_problem] problem
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_batch] batch on problem.lom_number = batch.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_specimen] specimen on problem.lom_number = specimen.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[Main_LOM_Form] main on problem.lom_number = main.lom_number
           WHERE problem.problem = '102' AND batch.batch IS NULL AND main.practice_code IN('HPMR', 'DOCTORs2')
           AND main.occurrence_date >=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.occurrence_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012')
           OR main.received_date>=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.received_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012')
```

However, the query returns the results as if my query was the SUM of

```
SELECT rank=COUNT(*)
   FROM    [LOM].[dbo].[lom_problem] problem
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_batch] batch on problem.lom_number = batch.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_specimen] specimen on problem.lom_number = specimen.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[Main_LOM_Form] main on problem.lom_number = main.lom_number
           WHERE problem.problem = '102' AND batch.batch IS NULL AND main.practice_code IN('HPMR', 'DOCTORs2')
   AND main.occurrence_date >=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.occurrence_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012')
```

and

```
SELECT rank=COUNT(*)
   FROM    [LOM].[dbo].[lom_problem] problem
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_batch] batch on problem.lom_number = batch.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_specimen] specimen on problem.lom_number = specimen.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[Main_LOM_Form] main on problem.lom_number = main.lom_number
           WHERE main.received_date>=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.received_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012')
```

How do I get the query to return the results with this part intact:

```
SELECT rank=COUNT(*)
   FROM    [LOM].[dbo].[lom_problem] problem
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_batch] batch on problem.lom_number = batch.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[lom_specimen] specimen on problem.lom_number = specimen.lom_number
       FULL JOIN [LOM].[dbo].[Main_LOM_Form] main on problem.lom_number = main.lom_number
           WHERE problem.problem = '102' AND batch.batch IS NULL AND main.practice_code IN('HPMR', 'DOCTORs2')
```

plus the filtering for either date range on top of that:

```
           AND main.occurrence_date >=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.occurrence_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012')
           OR main.received_date>=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.received_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012')
```

Thanks!

Edit:
 I need to filter based on a data range of main.occurrence_date and main.received_date. If the data range is present in either one or the other column, I need to return the count. However, the query as I have now returns the sum of the first part of the where statement and then the results from the second part (after OR). I thought it may have been just a syntax/formatting issue but was unsure.

Comment: Could you please make the question a bit more verbose?  Also, is a FULL JOIN necessary, or would an INNER JOIN work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget your parenthesis:

```
       WHERE problem.problem = '102' AND batch.batch IS NULL AND main.practice_code IN('HPMR', 'DOCTORs2')
       AND ((main.occurrence_date >=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.occurrence_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012'))
       OR (main.received_date>=Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND main.received_date <= Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012'))
```

EDIT: OK, let's try again. I believe acermate433s' suggestion would make it more readable:

```
       WHERE problem.problem = '102' AND batch.batch IS NULL AND main.practice_code IN('HPMR', 'DOCTORs2')
       AND (main.occurrence_date BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012'))
       OR (main.received_date BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'01/04/2012') AND Convert(datetime,'01/05/2012'))
```

Is this what you had in mind? It would count all records that have occurance_date in the specified range and all records that have received_date in the specified range, without counting them twice.

Comment: Should that fix the issue? I thought it was just a formatting issue... :/

Comment: No, it's a matter of operator precedence: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Comment: He could also use the BETWEEN keyword to make it more readable.

Comment: Nesting in parentheses will then change the order of statement evaluation to include both ranges as a subset instead of an additional set appended.

Comment: acermate433s --- I like the between statement idea for readability
@Olaf Yes that looks like it should work, I tested it and the output looks like I expected. Thanks for the help. I knew it was something simple that I missed....